# Joomla - Adding Hyperlink to K2 Item Image

Tags: joomla, k2

How do i add hyperlinks to item images in K2 (image attached):

[image: k2Image]

The images are then presented as portfolio grid on the homepage as below:

[image: portfolioGrid]

and I want them to link to external links.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an "Extra Field" of type "Image URL", and then, in the K2 item, add the external URL to the "Image URL" extra field.

After doing the above, you should override the K2 layout that displays your portfolio to link each image to the "Image URL". You can retrieve the value of each "Image URL" using json.